# Added C:\mingw\bin to path variable, gcc still not recognized

Tags: path, mingw

Installed minGW on my windows10 machine, added ';C:\MinGW\bin' to environment variables path, yet when I type 'gcc' into cmd it is still not recognized. 
Picture for reference.

[image: path variable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raw PATH variable is semicolon-separated, but the editor you're using splits it and displays one entry per row. You should have added a new row.

Keep in mind that environment variables are inherited from parent process and changes don't propagate upwards. This means that although editors do change initial values of variables, those changes are taken into account only once when you log in. For these changes to be fully in effect you have to log out and log in again (or simply reboot).